# How to properly cancel gestures where single and double tap gestures are competing?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, gesture

I am trying to solve an input puzzle, that turned out to be more complex than I initially thought. The original design, serving as a starting point to illustrate the issue, was fairly straight forward. It had to offer support for the following gestures:

- Pan (single finger)
- Tap

for the following widget topology:

```
+-------------------------------+
| container   +--------------+  |
|             | button       |  |
|             +--------------+  |
+-------------------------------+
```

The `container` should accept *pan* gestures, while the `button` should accept *tap* gestures. It must be possible to initiate *pan* gestures over any widget inside the `container` widget, including its child widgets, i.e. the `button` in this configuration.

The solution to this comprises two [`QGestureRecognizer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgesturerecognizer.html)-derived classes that implement logic to recognizer either gesture. The [`QGestureEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgestureevent.html)-handlers are equally straight forward: On touching the display, the `TapGesture` moves to the `Qt::GestureStarted` state, while `PanGesture` remains in `Qt::NoGesture`. When the finger is moved outside a tolerance window, `PanGesture` transitions to `Qt::GestureStarted`, which the event handler responds to by canceling out the tap gesture. This is done by calling [`QGesture::setGestureCancelPolicy(QGesture::CancelAllInContext)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgesture.html#gestureCancelPolicy-prop) followed by [`QGestureEvent::accept(gesture)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgestureevent.html#accept-2). If the finger is lifted off the touch surface without moving it outside the tolerance window, `TapGesture` is moved to `Qt::GestureFinished`, followed by canceling the *pan* gesture. (`PanGesture` and `TapGesture` are [`QGesture`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgesture.html)-derived classes, storing state machine state for either gesture type.)

Things started to get complicated, when the additional requirement to add support for *double tap* to the `button` widget was introduced. The *single tap* event is allowed to fire for the first tap that is part of a *double tap*.

Both `DoubleTapGesture` (storing state) as well as the `DoubleTapGestureRecognizer` are easily implemented. I am, however, having difficulty, producing a solution to canceling gestures. In contrast to the previous setup I can no longer cancel all other gestures, once a *single tap* gesture has been recognized, since a *double tap* gesture is potentially still in flight. Selectively canceling all gestures except for active *double tap* in response to a finished *single tap* seems the right solution. Except, the framework does not offer a way to manually cancel gestures. The only choices are: Automatically cancel all (`CancelAllInContext`) or no (`CancelNone`).

**Question:** Is it possible to control gesture cancelation in the `QGestureRecognizer` system to allow an implementation of the outlined requirements, and if so, how?